# UIImage imageNamed not work on ios 5.0

Tags: ios, uiimage

I use this code:

[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some@2x.png"]];

and it work on ios 4.3, but on ios 5.0 I don't see my image.

Anybody know which kind this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You normally don't need to include the @2x in the name - iOS should automatically pick the right filename (some.png or some@2x.png) depending on the scale of the screen. Have you tried this:

```
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some.png"]];
```

instead?

Answer (score 1):

As Martin (the other :) ) said, you should'nt add @2x if you have **both** yourImage.png and yourImage@2x.png.

I also listed many reasons of problems that could occurs with imageNamed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9698764/127493)