# Does @2x works on UIImage imageWithNamed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, retina-display

```
[self.distanceSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"handle-slider"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Let's take a look at that code.

If I use retina display, will the image called be handle-slider@2x instead of handle-slider?

Notice that this could raise an issue. Imagined if I load an image for the sole purpose of processing it and I really really want to load handle-slider, or handle-slider@2x? Then having iOS to override my decision and arbitrarily load @2x image will be kind of silly.

On the other hand most of the time, I used UIImage imageNamed to populate a button. In that case, it makes perfect sense to add @2x.

In any case, which path does apple eventually use and if possible, what's the reference?

I searched stackOverflow.

Most answers are inconsistent with one suggesting one or the other.

Comment: Check this stackquestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770990/uiimage-imagenamed-not-work-on-ios-5-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `[UIImage imageNamed:]` has exactly the information you want to know.

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the
>   specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching
>   image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image
>   data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the
>   resulting object.
>
> On a device running iOS 4 or later, the behavior is identical if the
>   device’s screen has a scale of 1.0. If the screen has a scale of 2.0,
>   this method first searches for an image file with the same filename
>   with an @2x suffix appended to it. For example, if the file’s name is
>   button, it first searches for button@2x. If it finds a 2x, it loads
>   that image and sets the scale property of the returned UIImage object
>   to 2.0. Otherwise, it loads the unmodified filename and sets the scale
>   property to 1.0.

Comment: That'll nail it once and for all. Who needs documentation if we have stackOverflow.