# Can not load UIImage on button

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I want to add UIImage on button，but the del.png can't show on my button，
What can i do?

I try many load Image Method，but no effect，such as:

```
UIImage* delImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"del.png"];

UIImage* delImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"del.png"];

UIImage* delImage =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"del.png"];

CalDelBtn *BookItem = [[CalDelBtn alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startPointX, startPointY, 75, 113) statuePicture:delImage];
```

Please give me some advice，thank you!!

Comment: You better show the implementation of CalDelBtn class. But the correct way of loading an image is UIImage* delImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"del.png"];

Comment: If it would be a normal `UIButton` I'd say that you need to use a method `setBackgroundImage:forState:`. But with a custom object... Show us the code of your `CalDelBtn` class

Comment: Also, you don't need to include the postfix when using [UIImage imageNamed:@"name.postfix"]. You can just do [UIIimage imageNamed:@"del"]. Remember that Del.png and del.png is the same thing in simulator, but not on a real device.

Comment: i create uiimageview in calDelBtn class,and i turn to another class to create CalDelBtn content, i want to add image on

Comment: I would like is not no set path for it..

Answer (score 1):

First, you image could be loaded with

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"del.png"];
```

This is the simplest way to load an image, so it should work with an autoreleased image.

Don't forget to add it to your xCode projet explorer! Here's a list of reasons for what your image generally woudn't display : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9698764/127493.

Then, add it to your button with :

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

for example. Does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your image is being added to your target?  Xcode 4.3 has a nasty habit of not including files into targets when you drag and drop.  So click on your project file on the left side of Xcode, go to *Build Phases* and see if your image is in the list under *Copy Bundle Resources*.