# UIImage imageNamed returns nil except for the first image

Tags: ios, null, uiimage, xcode8, imagenamed

I'm loading images from my app's image.xcassets using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"filename"]` method and **only the first image is loading correctly** but then the rest of the images returns nil and crashes the app. Below is my code:

```
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image0-150x277"]];
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1-150x277"]];
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2-150x277"]];
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3-150x277"]];
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image4-150x277"]];
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image5-150x277"]];
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image6-150x277"]];
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image7-150x277"]];
[self.imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image8-150x277"]];
```

And here is my addImage method:

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:image];
}
```

I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998544/uiimage-imagenamed-returns-nil) and tried everything in it including file names check and making sure the images are Retina 2x but nothing worked.
Any ideas on what might be wrong?

And here is the crash log:

`2016-10-14 15:28:10.280 Munasabah[38773:1038198] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d65134b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d0b221e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d58238f -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 1375
    3   Munasabah                           0x0000000108dcb669 -[CustomImagePicker addImage:] + 73
    4   Munasabah                           0x0000000108dc8012 -[FlipsideViewController viewDidLoad] + 994
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b4cd06d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b4cd4a0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010bd918d0 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b4a7d26 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 141
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b4e030b -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3956
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b4e36df -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 530
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010b4e31c5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
    12  Munasabah                           0x0000000108dc7632 -[MainViewController showInfo:] + 354
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b32db88 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010b4b32b2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010b4b35cb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010b4b24c7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b39b0d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010b39c7c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010b349a33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010bb3bb6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010bb34817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5f6311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5db59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5daa86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5da494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f712a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010b32bf34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    28  Munasabah                           0x0000000108dc430e main + 62
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010df2c68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

And a screen shot for the target membership:

[image]

Comment: Try storing images a temporary UIImage object and while debugging check if the object contains the image. (The eye icon shows you the preview of the image)

Comment: @Rikh What do you mean by storing images a temporary UIImage object?

Comment: @Ali Please check if you have initialized your array in which you are saving the images.

Comment: @DeepakSharma The array is initialized via `// Create and Initialize image picker
    self.imagePicker = [[CustomImagePicker alloc] init];` which is just before the image load in in the question. and I have the following in the `CustomIMagePicker` Code: `- (id) init {
 if ((self = [super init])) {
 _images =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 _thumbs =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }
 return self;
}`

Comment: Try UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

And when debugging, check if you can preview the image when you hover your mouse over the tempImage object. Or check if "tempImage" object is nil or not. 

Also make sure _images and _thumbs have both been initalized

Comment: @Rikh I tried `UIImage *tempimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1-150x277"];` and tempimage returns nil

Comment: @Ali Put same image in 1x and 3x as well and than try once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image names in the screenshot appear to be different than the ones you are using in the code! In the code it has a "277" in the end where as in the image name it is a "227"